# Parallel builds using all cores hang entire computer

Tags: 16.04, compiling, gcc, make

I have an Intel i9-9900K, a CPU with 8 physical cores and 16 threads, and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. When I compile a project that is able to fully use all 16 threads (i.e. 16 long-running parallel compilations on each, not bursts of short-term 100% usage), after a few seconds my entire computer freezes. The screen stops updating and I can't move the mouse. After about 5 minutes or so, things start updating again, but in the mean time half the compilations have failed and all of my other programs and even some background processes have crashed.

Compiling with e.g. `make -j12` instead of just `make` fixes this, but I'd like to be able to use all cores to compile. Is there any way to fix this? Shouldn't the OS be switching from the compilation process to other processes that need updating periodically?